# Do we pay for CloudFront distribution seperately that is created in API Gateway edge-optimised Custom Domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

when creating an edge-optimised `Custom Domain` in API Gateway, a CloudFront Distribution is created for which we do not seem to have any control over.

I have been looking at the pricing model and there's no mention of pricing for the CloudFront service. So, I'm guessing there wouldn't be but if we're going to be paying for the Distribution, it's going to be very expensive for us. Is there a documentation somewhere that talks about this? I just want to confirm it before I decide on it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only pay the API Gateway price, that is included on the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/) page.

When you create an Edge API Gateway endpoint the CloudFront distribution is not created in your account, in fact it is created in AWS account which hosts the API Gateway solution. So whilst it is distributed behind a CloudFront distribution it will not be within your account hence why the pricing will only include API Gateway pricing.

Comment: To use CloudFront and maintain more control over the distribution, you can use a [regional API with a custom CloudFront web distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/). But of course with this approach you will pay for the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: This is incorrect. The pricing page you linked to specifically includes a section "Edge Optimized and Regional APIs" where the additional data transfer costs are shown.